# Do I need a 2nd database to manage my PHP form, which provides users access to data from a large existing database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I am trying to create an application (basically just a form) using PHP to help users query an existing large MySQL database that is used to store test results. The plan has been to have a powerful server query and process data from the existing database and send reports about that data to the application to be displayed.
The existing database might be utilized for new types of test data, so the form must be able to change based on the new data types. It would also be great to be able to have sort of an administration panel for the application that could configure what options are available on the form for users to select, based on user requests. I don't really want to go so far as managing users accounts of this application, I want it to be generic.
It seems that it would be logical for me to create MySQL tables to manage the form. Is this wrong? Should tables that manage the application for accessing the large database exist in the large database itself, rather than creating a database specifically for the interfacing PHP application?

Form Generation:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";
$dbport = "";
//*/
//Data types lookup table: Array of short names each with 2nd dimension array
//containing table name in database, Human Name
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$data = array
   (//$type       $name[0] = table name         $name[1] = Readable name
    //key, short name?
    //Lookup table (parameter/form enable/disable? database?)
    'tbl1'=>array('table1_data_tbl1',               ''
        ),
    'tbl2'=>array('table2_data_tbl2',   ''
        ),
    'tbl3'=>array('table3_data_tbl3',              ''
        ),
    'tbl4'=>array('table4_data_tbl4',            ''
        ),
    'tbl5'=>array('table5_data_tbl5',                 ''
        ),
    'tbl6'=>array('table6_data__tbl6',                ''
        )
   );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//I COPIED THIS CODE
//-copied-Creates two dimensional array ($params) containing $_GET data, creating an
//-copied-array for each unique $_GET parameter containing their values.
if(isset($_GET["run"])||isset($_GET["data"])){
    $query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $params = array();
    foreach( $query as $param )
    {
        list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param);
        $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
    }
    //If the run has been selected: create region query, update url variable.
    if(isset($_GET["run"])){
        $id_run_rgn_query = implode(" OR id_run_rgn = ",$params["run"]);
        $id_run_PARAM1_query = implode(" OR id_run_PARAM1 = ",$params["run"]);
        $id_run_url = implode("&run=",$params["run"]);
    }
    //If data type has been selected: create run query?, update url variable.
    if(isset($_GET["data"])){
        $id_run_tbl4_query = implode(" OR id_run_tbl4 = ",$params["data"]);
        $id_run_tbl5_query = implode(" OR id_run_tbl5 = ",$params["data"]);
        $id_run_tbl3_query = implode(" OR id_run_tbl3 = ",$params["data"]);
        $id_run_tbl6_query = implode(" OR id_run_tbl4 = ",$params["data"]);
        $id_run_tbl2_query = implode(" OR id_run_tbl4 = ",$params["data"]);
        $id_data_url = implode("&data=",$params["data"]);
    }
    if(isset($_GET["data"])){
    }
}
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="addInput.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.dform.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname,$dbport);
if (!$db)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
}
?>
<img id="top" src="form/top.png" alt=""/>
<div id="form_container">
<h1><a></a></h1>
<div class="form_description">
    <h2></h2>
    <p>Retrieve testing data from database.</p>
</div>
<form id="myform">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var phpurl = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
    $(function() {
        // Generate a form
        $("#myform").dform({
            "action" : "createquery.php",
            "method" : "get",
            "target" : "blank",
            "html" :
                [
                    {
                        "name" : "data",
                        "id" : "data",
                        "caption" : "Select category of data:<br>",
                        "type" : "select",
                        "options" : {
                            <?php
                            //$data = ['tbl3','tbl4','tbl5','table1_cw','dist','tbl6','tbl2'];
                            $i=0;//increment for selected datatypes
                            $j=1;//increment for number of datatypes, used to omit final comma
                            foreach ($data as $type => $name){
                            echo '"'.$type.'" : ';
                            if(isset($params["data"][$i]) && ($params["data"][$i] == $type)){
                                echo '{';
                                echo '"selected" : "selected",';
                                echo '"html" : "'.$name[1].'"';
                                echo '}';
                                $i++;
                            }
                            else{
                            echo '"'.$name[1].'"';
                            }
                            if(sizeof($data)!=$j++){
                                echo ',';
                                //Formatting, PHP does not allow escape chars in single quotes
                                echo "\n                                    ";
                            }
                            }
                            echo "\n";
                            ?>
                        },
                        "size" : <?php echo sizeof($data);?>,
                        "multiple" : "multiple"
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "br"
                    }
<?php 
//List experiment runs available if data is selected
if(isset($params["data"][0])){?>
                    ,{
                        "name" : "run",
                        "id" : "run",
                        "caption" : "Select experiments:<br>",
                        "type" : "select",
                        "options" : {
                            <?php
                            // $totalruns is value returned from query:
                            //  SELECT COUNT(id_run) FROM run_run;
                            $totalruns=291;
                            $i=0;
                            $j=0;
                            $distinct = array();
                            $numdata = sizeof($params["data"]);
                            foreach ($data as $type => $name){
                                if(in_array($type,$params["data"]) && sizeof($distinct) < $totalruns){
                                    $j++;
                                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id_run_".$type.
                                           " FROM ".$name[0];
                                    $rs_result = mysqli_query ($db,$sql);
                                    $temp_distinct = array();
                                    $num_run = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);
                                    //Only get results if less than total runs
                                    if($num_run <= $totalruns){
                                        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs_result)){
                                            $temp_distinct[] = $row['id_run_'.$type]; // Inside while loop
                                        }
                                        $distinct = array_unique(array_merge($temp_distinct,$distinct));
                                    }
                                    //If the data type is involved in EVERY run, nothing is distinct
                                    else {$distinct = "";break;}
                                    $i++;
                                    if($i==$numdata){break;}
                                    //if(sizeof($distinct) >= $totalruns){
                                    //    break;
                                    //}
                                }
                            }
                            if($distinct!=""){
                                $distinctquery = implode(" OR id_run = ",$distinct);
                            }
                            else{
                                $distinctquery = "";
                            }
                            //*Verify it's working:    
                            echo '"777" : "Queries Performed: '.$i.'",';
                            echo '"778" : "Loops before break: '.$j.'",';
                            echo '"779" : "dataparam: '.$params["data"][0].'",';
                            echo '"780" : "Size: '.sizeof($distinct).'",';
                            //foreach($params["data"] as $)
                            $sql = "SELECT id_run,experiment_run FROM run_run";
                                    //"FROM run_run" .
                            if(!empty($distinctquery)){$sql=$sql." WHERE id_run = ".$distinctquery;}
                                    " ORDER BY id_run ASC";
                            $rs_result1 = mysqli_query ($db,$sql);
                            $num_run = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result1);
                            //echo '"num_run" : "'.$num_run.'",';
                            $i=0;
                            $j=1;
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result1)) {
                                echo '"'.$row["id_run"].'" : ';
                                if(isset($params["run"][$i]) && ($params["run"][$i] == $row["id_run"])){
                                    echo '{';
                                    echo '"selected" : "selected",';
                                    echo '"html" : "'.$row["experiment_run"].'"';
                                    echo '}';
                                    $i++;
                                }
                                else{
                                echo '"'.$row["experiment_run"].'"';
                                }
                                if($num_run!=$j++){
                                    echo ',';
                                    }
                            }
                            mysqli_close($db);
                            ?>
                            },
                        "size" : 7,
                        "multiple" : "multiple"
                    }
<?php
}//endbracket for data isset check
echo "]});";
if(isset($_GET["run"])){?>
            $("#myform").append('<table id="myTable"><tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Filter</th><th>Usage</th></tr>');//\n\
            $("#myTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>Param 1 Name</td><td>");                       
            $("#myTable td:last").dform({
                "html" : 
                    [
                    {
                            "type" : "checkbox",
                            "name" : "pePARAM1",
                            "id" : "pePARAM1",
                            "value" : "0",
                            "caption" : ""
                            <?php if(isset($_GET['pePARAM1'])){echo ',"checked" : ""';}?>
                        }
                    ]
                });
            $("#myTable td:last").after("</td><td>");
            $("#myTable td:last").dform({
                //"html" : 
                    //[
                    //{
                        "name" : "poPARAM1",
                        "id" : "poPARAM1",
                        "caption" : "",//</td><td>",
                        "type" : "select",
                        "options" :
                                {
                                    "xprm" : "X axis",
                                    "yprm" : "Y axis",
                                    "avg" : "AVERAGE",
                                    "grp" : "GROUP BY"
                                },
                        "size" : "1"
                        //"disabled" : ""
            });
            //Parameter Entry 2
            $("#myTable tr:last").after("<tr><td>Param 2 Name</td><td>");                       
            $("#myTable td:last").dform({
                "html" : 
                    [
                    {
                            "type" : "checkbox",
                            "name" : "pePARAM2",
                            "id" : "pePARAM2",
                            "value" : "0",
                            "caption" : ""
                            <?php if(isset($_GET['pePARAM2'])){echo ',"checked" : ""';}?>
                        }
                    ]
                });
            $("#myTable td:last").after("</td><td>");
            $("#myTable td:last").dform({
                //"html" : 
                    //[
                    //{
                        "name" : "poPARAM2",
                        "id" : "poPARAM2",
                        "caption" : "",//</td><td>",
                        "type" : "select",
                        "options" :
                                {
                                    "xprm" : "X axis",
                                    "yprm" : "Y axis",
                                    "avg" : "AVERAGE",
                                    "grp" : "GROUP BY"
                                },
                        "size" : "1"
                        //"disabled" : ""
            });
            //End of Parameter Select List
            $("#myTable td:last").after("</td></tr></table>");
            $("#myform").dform({
                "html" : 
                    [
                    {"type":"br"
                     //"caption":"</td></tr></table>"
                    },
<?php
//Parameter 1 Form
if(isset($_GET["pePARAM1"])){
?>
                    {
                        "type" : "div",
                        "class" : "pePARAM1",
                        "html" :
                        [
                            {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "name" : "PARAM1",
                                "id" : "PARAM1",
                                //"class" : "PARAM1"
                                "caption" : "Select Param 1 Name<br>",
                                "options" : {
                                    <?php
                                    $db=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname,$dbport);
                                    if (!$db)
                                    {
                                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
                                    }
                                    $sql = "SELECT id_PARAM1,subparam1_PARAM1,subparam2_PARAM1
                                            FROM PARAM1_PARAM1
                                            WHERE id_run_PARAM1 = ".$id_run_PARAM1_query
                                            ." ORDER BY subparam1_PARAM1 ASC";
                                    $rs_result = mysqli_query ($db,$sql);
                                    $num_PARAM1 = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);
                                    $i=1;
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)) {
                                        echo '"'.$row["id_PARAM1"].'" : ';
                                        echo '"Param 1 Name '.$row["id_PARAM1"].', Parameter of Param '.$row["subparam_PARAM1"].', Another Sub Parameter'.$row["subparam_PARAM1"].'"';
                                        if($num_PARAM1!=$i++){
                                            echo ',';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    mysqli_close($db);
                                    ?>
                                },
                                "size" : 7,
                                "multiple" : "multiple",
                                "disabled" : "false"
                            }  
                        ]
                    },
<?php } 
//Parameter 2 Form
if(isset($_GET["pePARAM2"])){
?>
                    {
                        "type" : "div",
                        "class" : "pePARAM2",
                        "html" :
                        [
                            {
                                "type" : "checkbox",
                                "id" : "element0",
                                "value" : "element0",
                                "caption" : "0"
                            },
                            {"type":"br"},
                            {
                                "type" : "select",
                                "name" : "region",
                                "id" : "region",
                                "caption" : "Select Region<br>",
                                "options" : {
                                    <?php
                                    $db=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname,$dbport);
                                    if (!$db)
                                    {
                                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
                                    }
                                    $sql = "SELECT id_rgn,id_param1_rgn,param2_rgn
                                            FROM region_rgn
                                            WHERE id_run_rgn = ".$id_run_rgn_query."
                                            ORDER BY id_rgn ASC";
                                    $rs_result1 = mysqli_query ($db,$sql);
                                    $num_rgn = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result1);
                                    $i=1;
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result1)) {
                                        echo '"'.$row["id_rgn"].'" : ';
                                        echo '"Param 1 Name '.$row["id_param1_rgn"].', Param 2 Name '.$row["param2_rgn"].'"';
                                        if($num_rgn!=$i++){
                                            echo ',';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    mysqli_close($db);
                                    ?>
                                },
                                "size" : 7,
                                "multiple" : "multiple"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
<?php }?>
                    {
                        "type" : "submit",
                        "id" : "submit",
                        "value" : "Get Data"
                    }
                ]
            });
        <?php }?>
    });
</script>
<script>
    var url = '';
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#data").click(function( event ) {
            var selectedValues = [];
            $("#data :selected").each(function(){
                selectedValues.push($(this).val());
            });
            selectedValuesUrl = selectedValues.join('&data=');
            window.location.href = "createqueryform.php?data=" + selectedValuesUrl;//"data=tbl4&run=7";//<?php //echo "data=tbl4&run=7"; ?>;
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $( "#run").click(function( event ) {
            var selectedValues = [];
            $("#run :selected").each(function(){
                selectedValues.push($(this).val());
            });
            selectedValuesUrl = "&run=" + selectedValues.join('&run=');
            window.location.href = "createqueryform.php?" + phpurl + selectedValuesUrl;//"data=tbl4&run=7";//<?php //echo "data=tbl4&run=7"; ?>;
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $( "#pePARAM1, #pePARAM2").click(function( event ) {
            //var phpurl = "<?php //echo $url; ?>";
            var param = $(this).attr('id');
            var flag = "&" + param + "=1";
            if ($(this).is(":checked")){
                    window.location.href = "createqueryform.php?" + phpurl + flag;
            }
            else
            {
                phpurl = phpurl.replace(flag,'');
                var div = '.' + param;
                $(div).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

_Note: I've replaced (messily) table names with generic names in an attempt to disguise the type of test data I'm working with, and the code is probably pretty horrible. This code is very unfinished. I'm still deciding on form objects I want to use for people to generate queries. The original question is referring to whether I should have a database (separate from the one I'm querying using this form) that can manage the form objects available for users, and to help expand types of data available.

Comment: Post the code here in the question itself

Comment: This looks like it has SQL injection vulnerabilities in it.

Comment: If I may comment this while you are starting to clean the script - I'd suggest you to consider updating version to PDO as that'd help in bigger picture.  From what you describe, it does sounds like a huge database transactions daily and there are bigger software available for that function. PDO have classes that opens the huge door to many (java, oracle, MSDB, etc) and would make things awful easy.  Meanwhile mysqli is good but is rigged to MySql only meanwhile PDO can be rigged to others, along with MySQL with better security from injection issues (just a feedabck of logic).

Comment: @halfer I'm on private company intranet. I'm more worried about getting something that works rather than something that is secure. I doubt anybody in my company that needs this data will intentionally try to break it, but I will definitely improve it when I get better at coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id make a table for each form element: category, experiments, param, region, etc in the existing database. There is no need for another database, unless it completely unrelated data, from a completely unrelated app.

Or make just one table called: 'testing_options' in the same database where the form elements share one column named 'key' that saves the type of element it is (category, experiments, param, region), and their value in a column named 'value'. Thus a key/value table to serve the form options.

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with that idea! It's nice to know other ways of approaching it.